# My login screen does not load when I start my flutter app

Tags: flutter, gradle, firebase-authentication

I don't know the gradle version and plugin to use with firebase authentication. The application runs fine when I load it through the debug mode and the login page shows up. But when I build the release apk the login page does not load up and the screen is blank. I had changed the gradle version from the default once  before.

PLUGIN : distributionUrl = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip

GRADLE DIST: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

Firebase auth version in pubspec : firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1

this is what I am currently using

Comment: I think you should try to be more specific with your problem, because hardly anyone will download the zip file and debug the problem and give a solution. Would it be possible for you to paste the specific file you think has a problem ?

Comment: Is the question clearer @Mayur

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that gradle version is your problem. Basically, flutter's default version is more than fine for firebase packages.

EDIT:
That's my gradle version and firebase_auth is working for me:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

Comment: Actually I had changed it once before, because my app had encountered this exact same problem and so I think that was the problem. Like it works when I run it through the debug mode but not when I build a release apk.

Comment: I've just provided my gradle version in the edit, but have no expertise on compatible versions

Comment: `Could not determine the dependencies of task ':firebase_core:compileProfileAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':firebase_core:profileCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:{strictly 2.0.0}.
     Required by:
         project :firebase_core
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common' that satisfies the 
version constraints:`                                                                                    
this is the error is get when I try and use your gradle version